# BAD_ACCESS on navigation item clicked

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller which opens `UIViewController` with `UIViewPicker` like this:

```
-(void)operationClicked:(id)sender {
    ChoseOperationViewController *picker = [[ChoseOperationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChoseOperationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:picker.view];
    [picker animateSlideOut];
}
```

ChoseOperationViewController is custom UiViewController class with nib that hold `UiViewPicker` and `UINavigationBar`

I've connected "Anuluj" (Cancel) button to the action as it's shown on the picture below:
[image]

When I click on the button I get the `-[ChoseOperationViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7569fd0` and cancelClicked method is not beeing called. Why is that?

Comment: what is printed on console when error comes?

Comment: nothing... its just BAD_ACCESS

Comment: enable zombies and see what message appears

Comment: updated question with console output

Comment: If this is happening on the simulator you should run the Zombie tool in Instruments.

Comment: it is happening because your object might be `de-allocated` before you using it, it is better to use property of `strong`  type if you are using ARC otherwise retain the object

Comment: changed all retain properties in the class to strong but the same thing is happening

Comment: did you make `ChoseOperationViewController` also a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
-(void)operationClicked:(id)sender {
    ChoseOperationViewController *picker = [[ChoseOperationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChoseOperationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:picker.view];
    [picker animateSlideOut];
}
```

This will create an instance of `ChoseOperationViewController` and add it's view as a subview to `self.view`. But when the method `-(void)operationClicked:(id)sender` returns, you have no strong reference to the instance you just created - therefore ARC will deallocate it.

When the user touches the cancel button, it will try to send the message to the instance that is deallocated and the app crashes.

**Solution:**

Add an instance variable to your `UIViewController`:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    ChoseOperationViewController *picker;
}
```

and change your code in `operationClicked` to:

```
-(void)operationClicked:(id)sender {
    if(!picker) {
         picker = [[ChoseOperationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChoseOperationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
         [self.view addSubview:picker.view];
    }
    [picker animateSlideOut];
}
```

This will prevent the `ChoseOperationViewController` instance from being deallocated